# vim. как выделить слово и перемещаться на следующее одинаковое слово выделяя его тоже а позже заменить все разом?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vim

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]stackoverflow мой дорогой) Как сделать сею команду? у меня выделяя слово курсор перемещаясь на другое слово тянет выделение по строкам вслед за собой выделяя все на пути. А вроде одну команду нашел, но она просто выделяет как бы маркером их, но ничего не делает с ними, будто просто показывает одинаковые слова но без возможности последующего форматирования

Comment: А что за команды, как вызываете? очень сложно угадать по таким описаниям.

Comment: vim. в нем пытаюсь найти такую команду. к примеру звездочка не помогает - просто перемещается к похожему, мне нужно выделение с последующим форматированием одинаковых слов или '/' тоже самое, обычное веделение vaw или viw выделяют но как дальше переместиться к одинаковому слову без выделение всего что попадет между ними не знаю

Comment: а что такое "последующее форматирование"? возможно, Вы просто не знаете о команде точка `.`, которая повторяет последнюю команду редактирование. И в этом случае `/` + `n`/`N` + `.` сделают все что нужно

Comment: снял специально для вас гифку, посмотрите если не сложно пожалуйста. Только мне нужно как это сделать при помощи vim. На данной гифке урок с интернета

Comment: похоже этот плагин как раз делает то, что нужно. https://github.com/mg979/vim-visual-multi   Если это можно выделить столбиком, то можно через блочный режим. Я же обычно пользуюсь точкой.

Comment: Благодарю! Просто машический плагин, странно что по дефолту не стоит такого,  обычное выделение и перемещение всегда ломает что то. Кстати я не смогу вас выбрать как лучший ответ, пожалуйста оформите ваш ответ в виде ответа а не комментария

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Похоже этот плагин как раз делает то, что нужно - [mg979/vim-visual-multi](https://github.com/mg979/vim-visual-multi)

Если это можно выделить столбиком, то можно через блочный режим.
Вначале через <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd> переходим в режим блочного выделения, потом стрелками вниз-вверх выделяем столбик и переходим через <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>i</kbd> в редактирование. Редактируем обычным способом (будет редактироваться только одна строка). После нажатия <kbd>Esc</kbd> все остальные строки отредактируются теми же командами. Ключевой момент, что они отредактируются "теми же командами", поэтому, если это команда, которая меняет по контексту, то оно и будет так.

Я же обычно пользуюсь точкой. [Точка повторяет последнюю команду редактирования](https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Repeat_last_change), даже если она очень и очень сложная.

Допустим, нужно все слова test заменить на data кроме комментариев. Пишем <kbd>/</kbd><kbd>t</kbd><kbd>e</kbd><kbd>s</kbd><kbd>t</kbd><kbd>enter</kbd>, видим выделенный текст. жмем <kbd>i</kbd> или любую другую команду редактирования и правим как надо (в нашем случае лучше наверно <kbd>c</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>w</kbd> и ввести новый текст). После этого жмем <kbd>Esc</kbd> А теперь, главное аккуратно - <kbd>n</kbd> - переходим к следующему найденному тексту и если он "правильный",  жмем <kbd>.</kbd>.

Как только это осваивается, другие редакторы просто отдыхают. Ведь <kbd>/</kbd> умеет искать регулярками.

- ещё почитать о точке - https://dev.to/iggredible/vim-use-dot-command-to-save-keystrokes-1c96
- почитать о других плагинах и возможностях - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11784408/vim-multiline-editing-like-in-sublimetext

Comment: только блочный режим — это `Ctrl`+`v`, а редактируется текст командой `c`, а не `I` — последняя вставляет текст перед выделением.

Comment: c  shift  я поспешил (хотя пальцы нажимают правильно), а вот I - это также переход в режим редактирования (как и i, a, A)

Comment: из визуального режима `a` и `i` вообще не работают, а OP всё же спрашивал о замене слов, но ни с `I` ни с `A` заменить ничего не получится...

Comment: после I вполне можно удалить с помощью delete необходимое кол-во символов.

Comment: с блочном режимом оно не сработает...

Comment: значит у меня вим неверный.

Answer (score 2):

Очень сомневаюсь, что выйдет сделать ровно так, как у вас
на картинке (по крайней мере, без плагинов), но возможно вас
устроит интерактивная замена:

```vim
:%s/name/address/gc
```

Флаг `c` говорит *Vim*, чтобы он спрашивал вас
каждый раз, нужно ли в этом месте производить
замену. Вы можете ответить `y` («да»), `n` («нет»),
плюс ещё несколько
вариантов. [Документация](https://vimhelp.org/usr_10.txt.html#10.2).

Comment: То что нужно чтобы решить мою задачу. Спасибо! А вы не знаете еще одну команду, к примеру у меня есть длинный блок <div здесь куча элементов></div> и я хотел бы командой переместиться к концу открывающего тэга и сразу быть в режиме написания.

Comment: Нажимайте на клавиатуре последовательно `f` `>` `a`. Тут `f` ищет следующий введенный символ в строке, а `a` переходит в режим вставки после текущего символа.